# sqlsrv_connect using windows authentication and php fastcgi.impersonate

Tags: php, sql, sqlsrv

I have some pages/scripts that connect to SQL databases, the connection string does not specify `UID` or `PWD` which from what i've read means that it passes on the windows authentication.
Obviously this breaks it when I enable php's `fastcgi.impersonate`.

Is there a way to have fastcgi.impersonate on and have it still use the current user's credentials for the connection string (ie set the `UID` as `$_SERVER['AUTH_USER']` but in this case how do I have it set the PWD?) ?

Any help would be appreciated, I have spent too many hours on this....